# Using custom trained Keras model with Sagemaker endpoint results ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to predict by loading pre-trained model in sagemaker, but I am getting the below error

> ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the
> InvokeEndpoint operation:  Received client error (400) from primary
> with message "{ "error": "Session was not created with a graph before
> Run()!" }

My code

```
def convert_h5_to_aws(loaded_model):
    import tensorflow as tf
    if tf.executing_eagerly():
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    """
    given a pre-trained keras model, this function converts it to a TF protobuf format
    and saves it in the file structure which aws expects
    """  
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils import predict_signature_def
    from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants
    
    # This is the file structure which AWS expects. Cannot be changed. 
    model_version = '1'
    export_dir = 'export/Servo/' + model_version
    
    # Build the Protocol Buffer SavedModel at 'export_dir'
    builder = builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    
    # Create prediction signature to be used by TensorFlow Serving Predict API
    signature = predict_signature_def(
        inputs={"inputs": loaded_model.input}, outputs={"score":    loaded_model.output})
    
    from keras import backend as K
    with K.get_session() as sess:
        # Save the meta graph and variables
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess=sess, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING], signature_def_map={"serving_default": signature})
        builder.save()
    
    #create a tarball/tar file and zip it
    import tarfile
    with tarfile.open('model.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
        archive.add('export', recursive=True)
        
convert_h5_to_aws(model)



import sagemaker

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='model.tar.gz', key_prefix='model')

!touch train.py #create an empty python file
import boto3, re
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

# the (default) IAM role you created when creating this notebook
role = get_execution_role()
import boto3, re
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

# the (default) IAM role you created when creating this notebook
role = get_execution_role()

# Create a Sagemaker model (see AWS console>SageMaker>Models)
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel
sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,
                                  framework_version = '1.12',
                                  entry_point = 'train.py')


# Deploy a SageMaker to an endpoint
predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                   instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
                                 

# Create a predictor which uses this new endpoint
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.model import TensorFlowModel

#endpoint = '' #get endpoint name from SageMaker > endpoints

predictor=sagemaker.tensorflow.model.TensorFlowPredictor(endpoint, sagemaker_session)
# .predict send the data to our endpoint
data = X_test #<-- update this to have inputs for your model
predictor.predict(data)
```

I also tried using different versions of TensorFlowModel

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is all of this code in a notebook? You want to make sure you are properly tarring your model artifacts and inference code. Make sure that you have your metadata for your saved model stored properly and also if you have an inference script with inference functions (handling pre and post processing) this should be wrapped in a code directory with the script in the tar file as well. Here's an example of deploying a pre-trained Sklearn model on SageMaker you can do the same with your pre-trained TensorFlow model.

Sklearn pre-trained example: https://github.com/RamVegiraju/Pre-Trained-Sklearn-SageMaker